# Smash! The metal pole descends upon the barren land

Tags: riddle

Smash!

The metal pole descends upon the barren land, scorched white by the burning sun.

Quickly, the metal cylinder crushes anything in its way and barrels down below the ground.

One hole formed. Two holes formed! Three holes slammed into the ground.

The part of the ground that flew off from the impact, I took home and placed in a large container. Three white circles they were.

I picked up the entire land and walked away. (This should be taken literally).

What is happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this a...

> Three-hole punch putting holes in a stack of paper. The holes are thrown in the garbage afterward.

Comment: Yep congrats! :D